# How to pass @State var between views?

Tags: swift, view, swiftui

I wan't to have a view, where I can't select a date, then I want to click on a button, which opens `GraphView`, and sends the `@State` var date to the other view, so I can use the date var in the GraphView.

This is what I have tried until now, but it shows the error:

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showGraph = false
    
    var dateFormatterMonth: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("M")
        
        return formatter
    }
    
    @State var date = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showGraph.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Show Graph")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showGraph){
            GraphView(date: date) {
            }
        }
        
        if showGraph {
            GraphView()
        }
        else {
            DatePicker("Date", selection: $date, displayedComponents: .date)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 20, alignment: .center)
            
            Text("Date is \(date, formatter: dateFormatterMonth)")
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Binding in `GraphView`, like

```
struct GraphView: View {
   @Binding var date: Date     // << here !!

...
}
```

and pass it like,

```
    Button(action: {
        self.showGraph.toggle()
    }) {
        Text("Show Graph")
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showGraph){
        GraphView(date: $date) {        // << here !!
        }
    }
    
    if showGraph {
        GraphView(date: $date)   // << here !!
    }
```

Comment: is there a way, in which I can define date as a global variable?

Comment: @SwagMand Please create a new post if you have a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Your error seems to be that you are trying to pass an argument to a initialiser without one. You can change your `GraphView` to something like

```
struct GraphView: View {

    @Binding var date: Date

    var body: some View { ... }
}
```

you can then call it like this `GraphView(date: $date)`.

That should do it.

Comment: is there a way, in which I can define date as a global variable?

Comment: @SwagMand EnvironmentObject might be what you're looking for if the variable is needed in multiple views. See more info n my answer below and make sure to check out the linked article.

Comment: You can define a global variable, however, I don't see a reason for that. You should use it when it can potentially be needed on any view of your app, something like login info for instance, in this case it seems to be something relevant to only one view in your app hence one variable passed on init sounds better

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "global" variable that can be used in multiple views you could consider using @EnvironmentObject.

Therefore you would have to define a new class in which you include date as @Published var. Then you would have to inject the environment object in your view(s) and can add it as @EnvironmentObject.

Here you can find more information: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views

In order to make preview in Xcode work with environment objects, remember to also add it to the View in the preview code using .environmentObject()

Comment: The thing is, that I want the user to be able to input a value. Then I want the user to press a button, which switches to another view. The other view, takes some information from an rest api. And what I want to do, is that depending on the value that the user entered the link is edited. So when the input is 1, the Link is www.example.com/1 and when its 2 the link is www.example.com/2